# Can not enable debug logs because there are "too many logs"

Tags: debugging, debug, debug-logs

I am trying to set up debug logs for a user, but every time I try it, I get the following error:

[image]

> Having an active trace flag triggers debug logging. You have 329 MB of the maximum 250 MB of debug logs. Before you can edit trace flags, delete some debug logs.

The message is pretty clear and I deleted all debug logs to set it up, but... Even without logs I still get the same error.

Screenshot of "all" my logs:

[image]

Did any of you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Developer Console, switch to the SOQL query and run this query:

```
SELECT Id FROM ApexLog
```

Select all the rows in this table (click the first one, scroll to the end and shift-click the last one) then click "Delete Row". OK the confirmation box and wait.